# Проблемы с индексацией в задаче про списки в Python

Tags: python

Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).

Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.

```
sp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sp2 = []
s = 0
n = len(sp)

if n == 1:
    print(sp)
n = n - 1    
for j in sp:
    s = int(sp[j-1])+int(sp[j-n])
    sp2.append(s)
print(sp2)
```

не понимаю, что не так, выдает ошибку, что индексация вне диапазона.

Comment: Закиньте сюда код и посморете что происходит. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле `for j in sp` у вас переменной `j` присваиваются значения элементов списка `sp`, а по смыслу вы хотите использовать индексы для доступа к элементам

```
for j in range(len(sp)):
```

К тому же при вычислении переменной `s` не надо приводить к инту значения, вы это уже сделали в первой строчке

Comment: спасибо большое! все получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, надо было сделать циклом for. Просто сделать проверку на первое и последнее число и написать сложение соседних чисел.

```
sp = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
sp2 = []
for i in range(len(sp)):
    if i == 0:
        sp2.append(sp[1] + sp[-1])  # для первого числа
    elif sp[i] == sp[-1]:
       sp2.append(sp[i - 1] + sp[0])  # для последнего числа
    else:
        sp2.append(sp[i - 1] + sp[i + 1])
    print(sp2)  # выводит [13, 6, 9, 15, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(map(int, '1 3 5 6 10'.split()))
x = list(map(sum, zip((*lst[1:], lst[0]), (lst[-1], *lst[:-1]))))
print(x)  # [13, 6, 9, 15, 7]
```